# Extracting files from zip file in c++ using COM

Tags: c++, com, zip

I've been looking for a way to zip files together to be sent by a web service and then extract them once they have been received. I found the code I've displayed here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280650/Zip-Unzip-using-Windows-Shell. The code for putting a file into the zip folder works fine which is:

```
BSTR source = L"C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\test1.txt\0\0";
BSTR dest = L"C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\test.zip\\\0\0";

HRESULT hResult;
IShellDispatch *pISD;
Folder *pToFolder = NULL;
VARIANT vDir, vFile, vOpt;

CoInitialize(NULL);

hResult = CoCreateInstance
(CLSID_Shell, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellDispatch, (void **)&pISD);

if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
{
  VariantInit(&vDir);
  vDir.vt = VT_BSTR;
  vDir.bstrVal = dest;
  // Destination is our zip file
  hResult = pISD->NameSpace(vDir, &pToFolder);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
  {

     // Now copy source file(s) to the zip
     VariantInit(&vFile);
     vFile.vt = VT_BSTR;
     vFile.bstrVal = source;

     VariantInit(&vOpt);
     vOpt.vt = VT_I4;
     vOpt.lVal = FOF_NO_UI;

     // Copying and compressing the source files to our zip
     hResult = pToFolder->CopyHere(vFile, vOpt);

     Sleep(1000);
     pToFolder->Release();
   }
   pISD->Release();
}
CoUninitialize();
```

The code that extracts the file from the zip file doesn't, which is this:

```
BSTR source = L"C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\test1.zip\\\0\0";
BSTR dest = L"C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\unzipto\\\0\0";

HRESULT hResult;
IShellDispatch *pISD;
Folder *pToFolder = NULL;
VARIANT vDir, vFile, vOpt;

CoInitialize(NULL);

hResult = CoCreateInstance
(CLSID_Shell, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellDispatch, (void **)&pISD);

if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
{
  VariantInit(&vDir);
  vDir.vt = VT_BSTR;
  vDir.bstrVal = dest;
  // Destination is our zip file
  hResult = pISD->NameSpace(vDir, &pToFolder);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
  {
      Folder *pFromFolder = NULL;
      VariantInit(&vFile);
      vFile.vt = VT_BSTR;
      vFile.bstrVal = source;

      pISD->NameSpace(vFile, &pFromFolder);
      FolderItems *fi = NULL;
      pFromFolder->Items(&fi); //----Fails Here!-----

      VariantInit(&vOpt);
      vOpt.vt = VT_I4;
      vOpt.lVal = FOF_NO_UI; // Do not display a progress dialog box

      // Creating a new Variant with pointer to FolderItems to be copied
      VARIANT newV;
      VariantInit(&newV);
      newV.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
      newV.pdispVal = fi;

      hResult = pToFolder->CopyHere(newV, vOpt);
      Sleep(1000);
      pFromFolder->Release();
      pToFolder->Release();
    }
  pISD->Release();
}
CoUninitialize();
```

The program fails at `pFromFolder->Items(&fi);`.

The destination folder "unzipto" exists before I run the program. Also trying to find anything on the "Folder" variable is very tricky as google brings back everything but what I'm looking for.

Is there anyone who can shed some light on this or even give me a clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: 10 years ago I knew so much more about COM ... but I think the way you set your BSTR values looks a bit off. But then...I used ATL when I did COM and _bstr_t type....

Comment: In what way do they look off? @BitTickler

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx <<-- Not only 0 terminated but also length prefixed normally.

Comment: thanks anyway but I found my error, wrong source file name! @BitTickler

Answer (score 0):

Ok after nearly going crazy trying to find out why this didn't work I realized that I had the wrong file name for the source file. I had test1.zip instead of test.zip and I missed it everytime I read over it! Simple as that.......